# How is this rotor setup flying?

Tags: helicopter, rotorcraft, vtol

I've been researching about helicopter flight without a tail rotor and the closest I've found is intermeshing rotors or this: https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-helicopters-have-rotor-blades-at-the-bottom

Looking at [this new method](https://youtu.be/2J55KHpgDVM?t=24):

Seen in this frame, the rotors are single winged and I'm guessing they rotate at opposite phases. What is this called and where can I find more information about it?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the two rotors move in opposite direction. This is called a co-axial rotor and is used by the Russian helicopter design bureau [Kamov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamov). A co-axial rotor can also be found on many [model helicopters for indoor flying](http://www.bestindoorrchelicopter.com). They are a subspecies of helicopters with contra-rotating rotors.

Helicopters with contra-rotating rotors do not need a tail rotor and are much easier to fly than Sikorsky-type helicopters, because they suffer much less from instability. This group also comprises intermeshing rotors like those used on [Flettner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flettner_Fl_282) or [Kaman K-Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaman_K-MAX) helicopters.

[image: Kamov Ka-32]

Kamov Ka-32 with co-axial rotors operated by HeliSwiss (picture [source](http://www.digicamfotos.ch/fotogalerie/data/media/51/_HRE2644_kamov_Ka-32_web.jpg))

[image: Kaman K-Max modified as an unmanned vehicle]

Kaman K-Max with intermeshing rotors modified as an unmanned vehicle (picture [source](http://www.operationnels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/K-Max_UAV_drone_umanned_aerial_vehicle_Lockheed_Martin_Kaman_Aerospace_American_United_States_006.jpg))

For more info, just follow the links.