# Could floppy rotor blades be usable?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller, rotary-wing

Autogyro and helicopter blades are more or less flexible, and when not stiffened by centrifugal force they droop noticeably. A extreme case would be that of fabric blades. They have been used at least once, as propeller blades in the airship ‘Parseval’.
Could fabric blades work as rotor blades of an autogyro?

[image: From page 75 of book 'Der Zeppelin' ISBN 9783613034099]

Comment: Do you mean a blade with no spar that just flops down like an old sock when not spinning?

Comment: Yes... Like the non-spinning blades in the left picture...

Comment: Many (if not all) "first flights" helicopter and De la Cierva's autogyros had for sure fabric-covered blades.

Comment: @sophit. Yes, but one thing is a rigid structure with a fabric covering (like many wings, fixed or rotating), and another very different is a completely 'floppy' blade, stiffened only by centrifugal force...

Comment: Then I don't think so since it would miss any torsional stiffness. Plus you need some ribs anyway in order to give an airfoil shape to the blade chordwise. But I agree that spanwise you wouldn't need any particular structure (if the fibers of the fabric has a proper layout to resist the centrifugal force); but then you couldn't change the pitch of the blade.

Comment: @sophit. No problem with the pitch... Some autogyros of the 30s did have variable pitch, but that was exceptional. Most historic autogyros were fitted with a fixed-pitch rotor, as well as almost all of present-day ones...

Comment: More than the missing pitch control, the missing torsional stiffness would be a paramount problem. Due to the aerodynamic environment typical of rotating wings, the blade would be torqued with different intensity along its span and in a oscillating manner. With no proper structure supporting this movement, the blade would flap in torsion just like a flag.

Comment: I think you would need more than 26 floppies, so you would run out of drive letters.

Comment: since there's no torque applied to an autogyro's rotor shaft (either by producing thrust  like helicopter rotor or harvesting power like wind turbines) the extreme case of "kites" flying in circle could become a valid rotor too. The ropes being floppy in all directions. One could autorotate using this, but not travel forward faster than centrifugal force allows to. Note the blades in op's first picture are actually rigid in one direction, they don't bend in sweep direction, so that they don't wind up around the small diameter hub

Answer (score 3):

For thrust to pull on the hub, a propeller blade must be able to transfer shear loads from the circumference to the center. Add a bending moment when the distance between the circumference and the hub becomes nonzero. This requires a stiff propeller.

With flexible blades thrust can be achieved when the blades form a cone from the lift force pulling them forward. This will be added to the tension created by the centrifugal force on the blades. From the right picture it seems that no such lift was achieved when the picture was taken.

However, the Parseval dirigibles could achieve [speeds above 40 km/h](https://av8rblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/15-german-parseval-type/), so the caption "… UND IN FAHRT" (… and in motion) is not quite correct. The complex hub arrangement actually allowed to change blade pitch and even to reverse pitch in flight.

[image: Austrian military dirigible M1]

Austrian military dirigible M1 (picture [source](https://www.fahrtraum.at/en/new-gondola-model-with-aircraft-motor-of-the-parseval-airship-1909/)), a Parseval-type dirigible built in 1909.

**Now to your question:**

> Could fabric blades work as rotor blades of an autogyro?

Maybe, when spun up before take-off. A typical autogiro does not need to power its rotor directly because it is [set in motion by the airflow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67606/what-will-be-the-lift-generated-by-the-in-wing-free-spinning-gyros-in-this-desig/67642#67642). Later Cierva autogiros did power the rotor in order to shorten their takeoff distance. Once in flight, all power is used to spin the propeller because driving the rotor would create undesirable torque which needs to be counteracted either by a [second rotor](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23309/how-is-this-rotor-setup-flying/23312#23312) spinning in opposite direction or by a [tail rotor](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54653/what-factors-govern-the-placement-of-a-helicopters-tail-rotor-left-or-right) like in Sikorsky-type helicopters.

It is important to keep the blades at a positive angle of attack so they will constantly produce enough lift to keep the autogiro afloat. While it seems that changing the attachment points of the two ropes which formed the leading and trailing edges of the propeller blades was enough for the Parseval propeller, the much higher aspect ratio of a typical autogiro blade will most likely restrict lift production to the blade section close to the root. Since a flat plate is indifferent to pitch changes, the pitch angle of such a blade would be only controlled by the tension in the ropes from the centrifugal force. This could work but I would rather use a stiff blade to make sure that their angle of attack is well controlled.

Also, a good airfoil will increase the range of possible angles of attack with good efficiency which is especially helpful for helicopters. Using a flat plate airfoil will definitely cost performance.