Why aren't there rotorcraft with sailcloth rotors?
I was wondering why no one has built rotorcraft, e.g a gyrocopter with rotors made of sailcloth fabric instead of aluminium or composite, because I thought that such a rotor would have to spin at a slower rpm to generate equal lift force or generate more lift, so the craft would need less engine power to lift off. I thought of this concept after watching a human powered helicopter lift off which had large sailcloth rotors that spinned slowly.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/99522/could-floppy-rotor-blades-be-usable

Got a link to the human powered helicopter?  And why might a sailcloth rotor generate more or equal lift at slower rpm?

Here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syJq10EQkog&pp=ygUYaHVtYW4gcG93ZXJlZCBoZWxpY29wdGVy
